# Xero XPM API - Job Task endpoint

Tags: xml, postman, xero-api

I have been exploring the XPM APIs recently and have come across a feature discrepancy between the API and the UI. Specifically, I have noticed that while it is possible to assign a staff member to a task using the UI, I have not been able to achieve the same result using the API endpoints v3.1, namely POST /job.api/task and PUT /job.api/task. It seems that assigning a user to a task is not supported through the API.

I wanted to check if this limitation is a known issue or if there is a workaround available. Ideally, we would like to automate the assignment of staff members to tasks using the API, as we aim to minimize reliance on manual UI interactions for task assignments.

I have tried to create a job with tasks by passing in this task with `<Assigned>` tag, but it is not getting created.

```
<Tasks>      
             <Task>
                <UUID>.....</UUID>
                <Name>......</Name>
                <TaskUUID>87264c74-a6a1-4f09-b6b5-7013f6ef1a6e</TaskUUID>
                <EstimatedMinutes>180</EstimatedMinutes>
                <ActualMinutes>0</ActualMinutes>
                <Description>simple descriptoin for testing purpose</Description>
                <Completed>false</Completed>
                <Billable>true</Billable>
                <Folder>testFolder</Folder>
                <Assigned>
                    <Staff>
                        <UUID>58714686-fe5a-450e-96ac-5538fab2bac2</UUID>
                        <Name>Some Random User</Name>
                        <AllocatedMinutes>180</AllocatedMinutes>
                    </Staff>
                </Assigned>
            </Task>
</Tasks>
```